# DataFrame from dictionary with nested lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have a python dictionary with nested lists, that I would like to turn into a pandas DataFrame

```
a = {'A': [1,2,3], 'B':['a','b','c'],'C':[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]}
```

I would like the final DataFrame to look like this:

```
> A  B  C
> 1  a  1
> 1  a  2
> 2  b  3
> 2  b  4
> 3  c  5
> 3  c  6
```

When I use the DataFrame command it looks like this:

```
pd.DataFrame(a)

>   A   B     C
>0  1   a   [1, 2]
>1  2   b   [3, 4]
>2  3   c   [5, 6]
```

Is there anyway I make the data long by the elements of C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
In [53]: df
Out[53]: 
   A  B       C
0  1  a  [1, 2]
1  2  b  [3, 4]
2  3  c  [5, 6]
In [58]: s = df.C.apply(Series).unstack().reset_index(level=0, drop = True)

In [59]: s.name = 'C2'

In [61]: df.drop('C', axis = 1).join(s)
Out[61]: 
   A  B  C2
0  1  a   1
0  1  a   2
1  2  b   3
1  2  b   4
2  3  c   5
2  3  c   6
```

`apply(Series)` gives me a DataFrame with two columns. To join them into one while keeping the original index, I use `unstack`. `reset_index` removes the first level of the index, which basically holds the index of the value in the original list which was in C. Then I join it back into the df.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one way is to deal with your dictionnary first ( I assume your dictionnary values contain either just list of values either list of nested lists - but not lists of both values and lists).
Step by step:

```
def f(x, y): return x + y

res={k: reduce(f, v) if any(isinstance(i, list) for i in v) else v for k,v in a.items()}
```

will give you:
    `{'A': [1, 2, 3], 'C': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'B': ['a', 'b', 'c']}`

Now you need to extend lists in your dictionnary:

```
m = max([len(v) for v in res.values()])

res1 = {k: reduce(f, [(m/len(v))*[i] for i in v]) for k,v in res.items()}
```

And finally:

```
pd.DataFrame(res1)
```

Comment: How 'outside-the-box' of you :)